# Reaching the tree END in oracle

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

I have one requirement...Suppose we have three table

```
1.A
primary key a_id

2.B
primary key b_id
foreign key a_id

3.C
primary key c_id
foreign key b_id
```

these tables contain `10 records` each.
**Need :** Now i want to delete a specific record from  each table.The record will be delete on a value supplied as a_id(primary key of table A).It will delete from A alright but how i can delete it from c as it does not contain a_id and this is only value known to us.

So how to do it...can anyone please let me know nay approach or anything.I need to delete a specific record from each table.starting point is a_id which is only thing known to us.

I am using oracle 10g and I cannot use any sys table. Thats a requirement as dba has given admin access.

Comment: b_id is primary key of table B and is acting as a reference in table C

Comment: Do you have privilege to `alter table` to make those foreign keys `on delete cascade`? Can you `create trigger`?

Answer (score 1):

you can do with the help of **ON DELETE CASCADE**  option

see here [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/553c0/1/2)

Comment: yes i can create trigger.I have spoken to a DBA and he told me that once it goes into production I wont be able to access sys table.Second , I am not sure on delete cascade.

Comment: yes i can create trigger.I have spoken to a DBA and he told me that once it goes into production I wont be able to access sys table.Second , I am not sure on delete cascade.

Comment: I just need to know the last table foreign key.Can we design a table which contain  primary key of all tables and do something with it.Is it a better approach or something else which can be suggested??

Comment: even if you are creating a different table for primary keys, you have to implement on delete cascade, or trigger , or multiple delete queries , if you had access for on delete cascade or trigger then that would be the best approach, rather than creating a different table.

Comment: can you let me know the logic which can be used in trigger...not coding but the logic.That would be of great help if you can share the logic which trigger will use

Comment: trigger as the name explains is triggered on event like-delete/update, so whenever there is delete on your table it will get triggered and delete the corresponding rows in the other tables.you can learn on this tutorial for more.. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: are we going to hard code the tables name as i am not getting how to fetch the child table primary key as it will used to delete the child table record.

Comment: your tables are not temporary right? so if they are not then there is no difficulty in hard coding the table names , as only they are the tables from which you have to delete the rows..

Comment: these are permanent tables and The tables which I have mentioned the question are just examples .there are 1029 tables in the DB.so hard coding wont be a right approach i think.

Comment: so ,are you deleting data from all the 1029 tables at one shot...??

Comment: Let me tell you the whole scenario. In my application when i register a number,Its goes to the particular table say A.That table A is connected to 59 tables.Each of those 59 tables may be connected to other tables.SO if I want to delete the data from A, first I have to delete the data from other dependencies first .I hope i have made myself clear.

Comment: i think you need to question the wisdom of a "BA" who says "no" to a delete cascade but "yeah ok then" to a trigger (which is in effect, rolling your own delete cascade, just with less efficiency and more prone to errors).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE A (a_id NUMBER, CONSTRAINT a_pk PRIMARY KEY (a_id));

CREATE TABLE B
(
   b_id   NUMBER
  ,a_id
  ,CONSTRAINT b_pk PRIMARY KEY (b_id)
  ,CONSTRAINT b_fk FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES A (a_id)
);

CREATE TABLE C
(
   C_id   NUMBER
  ,b_id
  ,CONSTRAINT c_pk PRIMARY KEY (c_id)
  ,CONSTRAINT c_fk FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES B (b_id)
);

--creating dummy data
insert into A select level  from dual connect by level<11 ;
insert into B(b_id,a_id) select level+10,level from dual connect by level<11;
insert into C(c_id,b_id) select level+20,level+10 from dual connect by level<11;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE delete_a(p_a_id IN a.id%TYPE)
IS 
 BEGIN
    --delete record from C first 
     DELETE FROM C WHERE b_id IN (SELECT b_id from B where a_id =p_a_id);
    --delete record from B 
     DELET FROM B WHERE a_id = p_a_id;
    --delete from the main table
     DELETE FROM C where a_id = p_a_id;
 COMMIT;
 EXCEPTION 
 WHEN OTHERS THEN 
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error while delete the recods '||SQLERRM);
 ROLLBACK;
 END delete_a;
```

Note:I have not tested the code ,but will work with this approach

Comment: HI this is a oracle specific query.I also did this using START WITH and connect by prior.But suppose or DB gets change then the procedure might not work.

Comment: @user728907:ARe you not sure which DB ur working in ?,and FYI start with and connect by is just to setup data for my tables ,and for other db's you must know the syntax .

Comment: yes i am aware of that i a using oracle 10g today.tomorrow it might be sql server so cant rely on  a DB Specific approach

Answer (score 0):

I use the table script as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE A (a_id NUMBER CONSTRAINT a_pk PRIMARY KEY,a_grade CHAR(1));
CREATE TABLE b
     (    b_id    NUMBER ,
          b_grade CHAR(1),
          CONSTRAINT b_pk PRIMARY KEY(b_id),
          CONSTRAINT b_fk FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES A(a_id) 
          ON DELETE CASCADE );
CREATE TABLE c
     (    c_id    NUMBER,
          c_grade CHAR(1),
          CONSTRAINT c_pk PRIMARY KEY(c_id),
          CONSTRAINT c_fk FOREIGN KEY(c_id)
          REFERENCES b(b_id)
          ON DELETE CASCADE );

BEGIN
INSERT INTO A VALUES(1,'a');
INSERT INTO b VALUES(1,'b');
INSERT INTO c VALUES(1,'c');
end;

/*below is the query that you provide in the table a to delete */

DELETE FROM A WHERE a_id=1;-- all tables values are deleted (parent and childs)

SELECT * FROM A;
SELECT * FROM b;
SELECT * FROM c;
```

hope this is what you needed.

Comment: On delete cascade not allowed